# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder

I'm trying to input a 5D tensor with shape ( 1, 8, 32, 32, 32 ) to a VAE I wrote:

```
self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d( 8, 16, 4, 2, 1 ), # 32 -> 16
        nn.BatchNorm3d( 16 ), 
        nn.LeakyReLU( 0.2 ),
        
        nn.Conv3d( 16, 32, 4, 2, 1 ), # 16 -> 8
        nn.BatchNorm3d( 32 ),
        nn.LeakyReLU( 0.2 ),
        
        nn.Conv3d( 32, 48, 4, 2, 1 ), # 16 -> 4
        nn.BatchNorm3d( 48 ),
        nn.LeakyReLU( 0.2 ), 
    )
    
    self.fc_mu = nn.Linear( 3072, 100 ) # 48*4*4*4 = 3072
    self.fc_logvar = nn.Linear( 3072, 100 )
    
self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear( 100, 3072 ),
    nn.Unflatten( 1, ( 48, 4, 4 )),
    nn.ConvTranspose3d( 48, 32, 4, 2, 1 ), # 4 -> 8
    nn.BatchNorm3d( 32 ),
    nn.Tanh(),
        
    nn.ConvTranspose3d( 32, 16, 4, 2, 1 ), # 8 -> 16
    nn.BatchNorm3d( 16 ),
    nn.Tanh(),
        
    nn.ConvTranspose3d( 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 ), # 16 -> 32
    nn.BatchNorm3d( 8 ),
    nn.Tanh(), 
)

def reparametrize( self, mu, logvar ):
    std = torch.exp( 0.5 * logvar )
    eps = torch.randn_like(  std )
    return mu + eps * std 

def encode( self, x ) :
    x = self.encoder( x )
    x = x.view( -1, x.size( 1 ))
    
    mu = self.fc_mu( x )
    logvar = self.fc_logvar( x )
    
    return self.reparametrize( mu, logvar ), mu, logvar 
    
def decode( self, x ):
    return self.decoder( x )
    
def forward( self, data ):
    z, mu, logvar = self.encode( data )
    return self.decode( z ), mu, logvar
```

The error I'm getting is: `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x48 and 3072x100)`. I thought I had calculated the output dimensions from each layer correctly, but I must have made a mistake, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: If you don't show us the `forward` it'd be difficult to to anybody to tell where exactly is the problem. But the most likely is the transition from `self.encoder` to either `fc_mu` or `fc_logvar`.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen My bad, I've edited the post to include the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
x = x.view( -1, x.size( 1 ))
```

Means you leave the second dimension(channel) as is and put everything else at the first dimension(batch).

And as the output of the `self.encoder` is `(1, 48, 4, 4, 4)`, doing that means you'll get `(64, 48)` but from the look of it I think you want `(1, 3072)` instead.

So this should solve this particular problem.

```
x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
```

Then you'll run into `RuntimeError: unflatten: Provided sizes [48, 4, 4] don't multiply up to the size of dim 1 (3072) in the input tensor`.

The cause is the unflatten here

```
nn.Linear(100, 3072),
nn.Unflatten(1, (48, 4, 4)),
nn.ConvTranspose3d(48, 32, 4, 2, 1)
```

Has to be `(48, 4, 4, 4)` instead.

Comment: That fixed everything! And thanks for catching the unflatten mistake